# Produce the set of all Equivalent Classes

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

Consider the equivalence relation $C_m = \{(x,y)\in\mathbf{Z}\times\mathbf{Z}|x\equiv y$ (mod $m$)$\}$ where $m\in\mathbf{Z}^{+}$

We are required to determine the set of all equivalence classes for $C_m$

This is what i think $\mathcal{F}_m = \{i\in\mathbf{Z}|\{i\equiv j$ (mod $m$)$|j\in\{0,\pm1,\pm2,...,\pm m-1\}\}\}$.

Would it be correct to state that $|\mathcal{F}_m| = 2m-1$ ?

Comment: I would guess your answer might look like $($arithmetic progression, arithmetic progession$)$  Why do you say $-1$ belongs to a different equivalence class from $m-1$?

Comment: In your definition of $\;\mathcal F_m\;$ , observe that for example $\;(m-1)+1=0\pmod m\implies m-1=-1\pmod m\;$ , and thus you're counting too many different classes...

Answer (score 1):

When $\equiv$ is an equivalence relation on a set $S$ and $x\in S,$ the equivalence class of $x,$ usually denoted by $[x]_{\equiv}$, is $\{y\in S:y\equiv x\}.$

In this case we have $y\equiv x \iff \exists n\in \mathbb Z \;(y=mn+x)\iff y\in \{mn+x:n\in \mathbb Z\}.$ Therefore $[x]_{\equiv}=\{mn+x:n\in \mathbb Z\}.$

Example: When $m=2$ we have $[0]_{\equiv}\;=\{2n:n\in \mathbb Z\}$ and $[1]_{\equiv}\;=\{2n+1:n\in \mathbb Z\}$.

$F_m$ has exactly $m$ members because every $y\in \mathbb Z$ is equivalent modulo $m$ to exactly one member of the set $\{0,...,m-1\}$. For example with $m=8$ we have $-5\equiv 3\pmod 8$.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of ideas for you to fill in the details:

$$\text{Prove that}\;\;[0],\,[1],\ldots,[m-1]\;\;\text{are all different classes in}\;\;\Bbb Z$$

$$\text{Prove that for any}\;k\in\Bbb Z\;\text{ there exists}\;\; \;0\le i\le m-1\;\;s.t.\;\;k\in[i]\;$$

Comment: So what your saying is $F_m = \{i\in\mathbf{Z}|\{i\equiv j$ (mod $m$)$|j\in\{0,1,2,...,m-1\}\}\}$ where $|\mathcal{F}_m| = m$.

Comment: @AtifFarooq Yes indeed, though your notation could be clearer.

Comment: How about $F_m = \{[0]_{C_m},[1]_{C_m},[2]_{C_m},...[m-1]_{C_m}\}$